# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException does not let me finish my function

Tags: c#, appdomain, streamwriter, unhandled-exception

Currently, I have a method that is called when there is an unhandled exception. All this does is log the exception to a dump file. However, the streamwriter does not write the full information I'd like it to write to the file. I assume this is because the program has shutdown before it can finish writing the file.

Is there any way to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Flush` on the stream writer

Comment: That's done the trick, thanks. I'll accept the answe when SO lets me :)

Answer (score 2):

use

```
using(var stream = new StreamWriter(@"C:\..."))
{
    //logic
}
```

This will make sure, that stream will be closed and flushed in the `finally` section.

Comment: I normally prefer to dispose things myself, but thanks too :)

Comment: `I normally prefer to dispose things myself` - why not to take advantage of C# syntax? Just makes code shorter. By the way, I bet you aren't checking for null in finally section (just kidding, you do check for null, aren't you?)

Comment: It's just an odd quirk that I have: kind of like I barely ever use var. :)

Comment: Ok, I see. some bugs happens because of different quirks in the system.